# Transfer data from c++ to python in real time

Tags: python, c++, ipc

I would like to ask a question about transferring data from c++ to python in real time.

My situation is :

1) I am generating data every 1 ms in c++,

2) I would like to stack data for certain amount of time and make a dataset,

3) I would like to run some machine learning algorithm written in Python without turning of c++ program.

So far, I have thought about several things :

option 1 ) Save the dataset as a txt file and read it from python. But this seems too slow due to I/O process.

option 2 ) Use IPC such as zeromq. I am quite new to IPC, so I am not sure if it is the thing I really want. Also, among the multiple methods (mmap, shared memory, message queue, ...), I do not know which one is the best shot for me.

option 3 ) Use UDP. From my understanding UDP sometimes sends the same data twice, or skips the data, or mixes data up (e.g. previous time step data arrives later)

Is there any recommendations I need to search and study?

Comment: It's a pretty broad question, but consider how long the python process will take to run versus the time it takes to read the data from a file. I'm going to guess that file i/o would be a small fraction of the overall time. It's certainly the easiest thing to do and it may be fine. If not then you have a baseline so you can measure improvement. Imagine spending a bunch of time trying to implement what you think might be the fastest way out there and then finding out the simple way was faster or just fine after all.

Comment: `UDP` sounds like one specific method of *option 2)* it is a means of `IPC` (unreliable without additional management from the app). If you want to do that reliably then you can just use `TCP`. On a local connection both should be super fast. You could also use named pipes? (probably easier).

Comment: Start with stupid and simple, but wrap it in an abstraction so that you can replace the stupid/simple approach with something smarter/more-complex if you have to without having to rip up the rest of the program.

Comment: ZeroMQ is a fast and safe TCP socket transmission with a reliable queue, it is ready to use on many languages, for Python is `pyzmq`, and there is C++ library too.